# Use atrun via launchD on MacOS

Tags: macos, bash, launchd, at

I'm trying to schedule a job using the at-command in a script invoked by a launchDeamon.
This doesn't seem to work.
The launchD for atrun is running.
Atrun, cron and terminal all have full disk access.

I'm creating my own .plist / launchD to call a script that schedules a job.

The launchD is running and executing the script, the job however does not get created.

Running the script in Terminal with sudo works just fine.

Using stdout/stderror in my .plist I can see that it cannot open .lockfile located in /usr/lib/cron/jobs. When listing the contents of the path there is no .lockfile for whatever reason. Since running it via Terminal - sudo is working fine and looking at the log, I assume this is just a permission issue.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was surprisingly simple: the shell you use (e.g. Bash, Sh etc.) to create the "at" job needs full disk access to create the job file in "/private/var/at/job" when the script is called by a launchD.